# tab bar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I have made a tabbar application which display images in detail view i have two views first and seconed  at the image view i have a button addtofavorities i want to click on addtofavorities and add the image name into seconed view.seconed view is a table view

Comment: Please edit **your** post, not other people's posts

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the image name to other view then, just take a string in other view import other class in first view add that value to the string of other class and send to other class, it will carry that value to your other view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to explain yourself a bit better. What do you want to do? Does your implementation crash?
Based on your (lack of) explanation, it's as simple as set a selector to your favourite button and change second view.

Comment: IMHO, this should be a comment, not an answer.